# Display * for password in <apex:inputSecret> in VF page

Tags: visualforce

I am using following code to display the password on the VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="Docusign Password">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Password" />
                        <apex:inputSecret value="{!docusignTestPassword}" label="Password"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

But, on VF page, the password field is displayed as blank. I want password fields to display *.
[image]

Comment: As this is an _inpu_ field I would expect to see an editable area. Is this field read-only in the Field Level Security (FLS) settings of your profile?

Answer (score 3):

In order to render the previously entered value in the masked format, you will have to set the `redisplay` attribute of `<apex:inputSecret>` to true. By setting this attribute to true, it will display your value from controller in masked format.

From the salesforce documentation at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputSecret.htm) link, `redisplay` attribute on `<apex:inputSecret>` is

> A Boolean value that specifies whether a previously entered password
>   is rendered in this form. If set to true, the previously entered value
>   is displayed with its mask. If not specified, this value defaults to
>   false.

So, your visualforce page should be

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="Docusign Password">
    <apex:outputLabel value="Password" />
    <apex:inputSecret value="{!docusignTestPassword}" label="Password" redisplay="true"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Ideally, it should display you an input box with masked values.

Answer (score 0):

<apex:inputSecret value="{!docusignTestPassword}" label="Password" redisplay="true"/>

Be advised that if the merge variable docusignTestPassword has a value and anyone displays the contents of the page in HTML, they will see the value="" attribute on the page with the old value.  So, unless you mask the old value on the back end after retrieving it, the tag only protects against a look-over-the-shoulder take of an attack.  Anyone getting to the page will have access to the prior value.

It's also rather annoying in that when you start typing in the field, it doesn't completely erase the prior value.